# Operand should contain 1 column(s) MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1241

does anyone knows what's going on with this query please ?. What I am trying to do is if `courseID` in `elective_modules` table *doesn't exist* in `group_elective_modules` table, then print all  exit in `group_elective_modules`. But I keep getting the error **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

**Here is my query**

```
$alternativeEQuery = 
"SELECT elective_modules.courseID,elective_modules.yr 
 FROM elective_modules
 WHERE elective_modules.yr = '$year1' 
 AND elective_modules.courseID 
 NOT IN 
     (SELECT group_elective_modules.moduleID,group_elective_modules.courseName 
 FROM group_elective_modules 
 WHERE group_elective_modules.courseName = '$courseTitle'
 AND elective_modules.courseID = group_elective_modules.moduleID)";

$alternativeEResult = mysql_query($alternativeEQuery) or die($alternativeEQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Comment: You have the possibility of an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @Joe.I already escaped all the variables above of code before I pass them as a parameter !! Thanks

Comment: The `IN()` operator expects 1 column if you are using a subquery to supply values. You can't select more than 1 column. If you think about it, it's logical also.

Comment: @N.B.Thanks,that does make sense when you mentioned **IN** operator. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two columns in the subquery here:

```
(SELECT group_elective_modules.moduleID,group_elective_modules.courseName 
 FROM group_elective_modules 
 WHERE group_elective_modules.courseName = '$courseTitle'
 AND elective_modules.courseID = group_elective_modules.moduleID)
```

Either use the right one, or add in a second `not in` clause and use the other column name there.